# How to revert focusable false in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

**When i do:**

```
my_edit_text.setFocusable(false);
```

*and then*

```
my_edit_text.setFocusable(true);
```

*The second code line is not working, the field remains unfocusable.*

**Someone understand why? How can I resolve that?**

Answer (score 0):

**try this code**...

```
edit_text.requestFocus();
```